# How do you filter an ASP.NET Entity Framework Bound ListView via DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, listview, dropdownlistfor

I am having some trouble figuring out the best way to filter an Entity Framework Query with the results of a DropDownList's Selected Value to fill a ListView Control.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Function ListViewProducts_GetData() As IQueryable

    Dim strVendorName As String = ddlFilterVendor.SelectedValue

    Dim myEntities As New InventoryProductsEntities()
    Return (From product In myEntities.InventoryProducts
           Order By product.ID Ascending
           Where product.VendorID = strVendorName
           Select product).Take(ddlDisplayRecords.SelectedValue)

End Function
```

This is pretty rough right now, but I would like to be able to filter this data by vendor, and then page it, but I cannot get the ListView to display the updated queried data. It just continues to display the same data as before, even with a ddlFilterVendor.SelectedValue change.

The drop down list code is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterVendor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVendor" DataTextField="VendorID" DataValueField="VendorID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am stuck at this point.... I was thinking about posting the ddlFilterVendor.SelectedValue to the QueryString and reloading the page, but I would imagine that there should be an easier way to do this. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

The SqlDataSource Code is as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceVendor" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [VendorID] FROM [InventoryProducts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You are using SqlDataSource with the drop down. Can you post a definition of that?

Comment: Why are you not using the [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Andrei - I added the SqlDataSource Code. The filter will work on page load, but selecting another item from the DropDownList will cause a post-back, run the ListViewProducts_GetData() Function, but will not change the items in the ListView that were shown when the page was first loaded.

Comment: @OneFineDay - I was having some trouble with flexibility when it came to ModelBinding (If that is what the EntityDataSource does)  the ListView, and I could not get it to Update from the EditTemplate. This is probably a question that I should ask about in another post...

Comment: I have used it with a `GridView` and the Templates should be roughly the same. Are far as updating you need to cast the listview item to the Entity type and update the model with it and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. In the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event, I called the following method:

```
ListViewProducts.DataBind()
```

This re-queried the database with the appropriate Vendor filter, as shown in code snippet:

```
Public Function ListViewProducts_GetData() As IQueryable

    Dim strVendorName As String = ddlFilterVendor.SelectedValue

    Dim myEntities As New InventoryProductsEntities()
    Return (From product In myEntities.InventoryProducts
            Order By product.ID Ascending
            Where product.VendorID = strVendorName
            Select product).Take(ddlDisplayRecords.SelectedValue)

End Function
```

Thanks!